# Vim XMLns context awareness

Tags: xml, vim, omnicomplete

I've used Vim's `g:xmldata_` to describe XML possible elements to be able to use omni-compete for XML. The problem is not each `A` node has `a0`, `a1`, `an`. Sometimes `A` node has only `a0`. And the documentation of
the `a0` and `A` is different and depends on parent of `A`.

```
E
|
|--A
|  \-a0     // documentation of E.A.a0
|  \-a1
|
\--B
   \-A
     \-a0     // documentation of E.B.A.a0
```

Documentations of A and a0 are different. But user will see the same help-text in the complete preview window.

Here is the test xmldata to play with. Put this

```
let g:xmldata_test = {
\ 'vimxmlroot': ['E'],
\ 'E': [['A', 'B']],
\ 'B': [['A']],
\ 'A': [['a0', 'a1']],
\ 'vimxmltaginfo': {
\ 'a0': ['', 'documentation that only confuses an user'] }}
```

in autoload/xml/test.vim
And execute while edit some xml document

```
:XMLns test
```

To bring up the complete window just type < and press C-X C-O

Is there any way to tell Vim for which `a0` I want to set help information?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this interesting-looking usage of vim, but the definition of the 'A' key in your g:xmldata_test example of course makes it impossible to distinguish between "toplevel A" and "A the subelement of B". If it were possible to define g:xmldata_test keys like 'B/A' then you could presumably do what you want. Do you have a link to good/complete documentation (or source code) for this feature?